# Convert a file array to string array JAVA

Tags: java

I need some help.

I use this code to get the files in a folder as an array .

```
String fileDir = Directorty;
File dir = new File(fileDir);
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.html");
files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

But I want to write a file with only the files in that folder and not the path. 
The result is:

```
[C:\Askeladden-17-12-2014\.html, C:\Askeladden-17-12-2014\barnetv.html, C:\Askeladden-17-12-2014\britiskebiler.html, C:\Askeladden-17-12-2014\danser.html, C:\Askeladden-17-12-2014\disipler.html, C:\Askeladden-17-12-2014\donald.html, C:\Askeladden-17-12-2014\ekvator.html, C:\Askeladden-17-12-2014\engelskspraak.html]
```

But I want to have it without the path

```
C:\Askeladden-17-12-2014\
```

I have been looking around the webs to find some answers, but no luck. 
Using this:

```
strFiles = Arrays.toString(files);
```

Gives a string presented as an array with [] in each end, and I am not able to get

```
strFiles.replace("C:\\Askleladden" + date +"\\", "");
```

to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to iterate the files array and call `getName()` for each file:

```
String[] names = new String[files.length];
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   names[i] = files[i].getName();
}
```

Comment: You will soon get to the harsh reality of StackOverflow @KarlNorway

Comment: @AlexR Its a figure of speache here in Norway. I know its not a trick but good coding ;)

Answer (score 2):

Java 1.8, if you want get as List, just remove cast and to array

`String[] files = (String[])Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles(filefilter))
                  .stream().map(x->x.getName())
                  .collect(Collectors.toList())
                  .toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

Please find the solution below with proper comments.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
public class fileNames {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Get the Directory of the FOLDER
        String fileDir = "/MyData/StudyDocs/";
        // Save it in a File object 
        File dir = new File(fileDir);
        //FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.html");
        //Capture the list of Files in the Array
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            System.out.println(files[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `File`s `getName()` method:

```
File file = new File("myFolder/myFile.png");
System.out.println(file.getName()); //Prints out myFile.png
```

Comment: How will this work when there are several files in the folder.